# JQuery: How to determine if a radio button has been selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I determine if my radio buttons are selected?

For example:

```
if ( radio_button_selected ) {

// do something

} else {

// do something else

}
```

Comment: This question has been asked before numerous times. Please search for the answer before asking the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138300/validating-a-form-with-a-radio-button/4138350#4138350

Answer (score 7):

You can use this selector to determine if any are checked:

```
jQuery("input[name='my_button_group']:checked")
```

So for example:

```
if (jQuery("input[name='my_button_group']:checked")) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: why do I need **.length > 0** ?

Comment: @StaceyH - you don't in JavaScript, but this is a much faster selector than the other answer (because of the `input`).

Comment: @Nick Craver ...wasnt sure if you can see my comments from my post..but take a look

Comment: @John - I suppose you *might* need that check, but it would also be pretty poor naming if a checkbox had the same name as a radio, since the value would always screw up the form serialization output :)

Comment: @Nick..  Agreed but I have seen the situation where a checkbox and a radio had the same name but one was disabled and the other enabled.  This changed due to other elements on the form.  This question just really made me think about that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your radio button `rb` already selected through other means, you can do:

```
var rb = $('whatever selector');

// other code

if (rb.is(':checked'))
{
  // code
}
```

Comment: +1 for being able to re-use rb for something else in the code (like getting val())

Comment: @jelbourn `rb.checked` is a better choice - it's faster and more readable.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: `checked` is not a property of a jquery list object. The actual DOM object has the `checked` property.

Comment: @jelbourn Yes, my mistake. `rb[0].checked` is the correct solution (and it is still faster).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: You're definitely right about it being faster; I did a little experiment and found it to be roughly 22 times faster.

Comment: @jelbourn Yea, it's astonishing how much faster the built-in browser API is compared to jQuery. I did a similar test the other day comparing `this.parentNode.id` to `$(this).parent().attr("id")` and the results were similar (around 50x faster if I remember correctly). Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the element already, you can use its `checked` property:

```
$('input[type=radio]').focus(function(){
    // "this" is the element that was clicked

    if (this.checked) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't that pointless since if the user "clicked" a radio button, it will always be "checked", hence you'll NEVER get to the ELSE condition of your code above

Comment: @StaceyH A very good point. Changed to `focus` to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("input[name='yourRadioName']:radio:checked").length) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: @Nick Craver... There is a difference in Justin's method vs. mine.  the `:radio` ensures that a radio button is selected and not just any checked input with the name "yourRadioName"..  However you are right using input would execute faster.