# JQuery: get radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="0" selected="selected" style="display:none" />
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1" />1+
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="2" />2+
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="3" />3+
```

JQuery to get the selected radio button

```
$('input:radio[name=abc]:checked').val();
```

Why doesn't the code above work on page load, BEFORE a user selected a radio button? It's strange because the code above does work AFTER a user selected a radio button.

It seems to me that I have set the default radio button value to be `0`, but if you

Meaning, if the radio button value is selected, return the selected value - otherwise, return 0 (when no value has been selected)

Comment: Do you have the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @StaceyH This is the fourth time you've asked this question. Please edit a previous question if you need to clarify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: How to determine if a radio button has been selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139165/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-radio-button-has-been-selected)

Comment: @mway - No, should I? If so, why?

Comment: @StaceyH: because *that* way the jQuery would run on the document's (DOM's) 'ready' event, as opposed to running as the browser encounters the jQuery/JavaScript (which would be before it constructs the DOM, and so *before* the elements you want to manipulate **exist** - assuming you've put your `<script>` in the document `head`).

Comment: Stacey, Javascript will execute before the DOM (Document Object Model) is ready...meaning that the elements (in this case, the radios inputs) don't exist yet. The event observation of $(document).ready() lets Javascript know to execute when the DOM has become available.

Comment: @StaceyH You posted 3 very similar questions in the last 1 hour. You don't have to do that. You can just edit your original question to add new information, for example, a follow-up question...

Answer (score 23):

You are using the wrong attribute. For radio buttons you have to use the `checked` attribute and not the `selected` attribute.

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked">
```

or just:

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

Comment: @StaceyH, you should do as @Šime suggests, and change `selected` to `checked`. @jnpcl, perhaps a little too harsh; I don't think @StaceyH is being *intentionally* obtuse.

Comment: @David: Read @lonesomeday's first comment on the initial question.

Comment: Tried your wisdom with OP's original JQuery: $('input:radio[name=abc]:checked').val();  and it worked! @Ashish Babu I tried your JQuery and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 20):

First correct the attribute to checked and remove selected attribute which is wrong and then use the following code.
t will get the selected value of the radiobutton at button click.
ex for list

```
   $("#btn").click(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Radio has the attribute `checked`, not `selected`

```
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="0" checked="checked" style="display:none" />
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1" />1+
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="2" />2+
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="3" />3+
```