# How to read a radio button value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rendering a form with radio buttons using JQuery and then trying to read the value of the selected radio option when the submit button is clicked. However all i get is undefined values.

I tried to return .val() and read an attribute of the input element like .attr("name"), but everything returns 'undefined'.

Here is how i create the input elements inside a form:

```
  let options = $("<div></div>");
  for (let answer of questionnaire[currentQuestion].answers) {
    let a = $("<input></input>").attr({
      "name":questionnaire[currentQuestion].name,
      "type":"radio",
      "value":answer.value
    });
    let l = $("<label></label>").text(answer.label);
    options.append(a,l);
  }
```

When inspecting the HTML elements in browser page, each input element looks like this:

```
<input name="comfortfood" type="radio" value="steak">
<label>Medim-rare flat iron Steak</label>
```

And this is how i try to read the value:

```
$('input:radio[name='+questionnaire[currentQuestion].name+']:checked').val()
```

I checked other threads here (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139437/jquery-get-radio-button-value)) but still can't get my code to work. I'm new to all this so probably missing something obvious.

**EDIT**: I ended up creating a click event on each radio button and then reading value with `event.currentTarget` as suggested by @Sakata Gintoki in his comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my snipet code bellow:

1. You should declare class name to use in query -> avoid confusing when we have many `divs`
2. In the function which is used to get the value, you should get exactly target element that you have just clicked. (`event.currentTarget`)
3. Should use `forEach` instead of `for`
4. In case you get from another action (by clicking another element), you should get child element from parent element

Hope it's useful.

```js
let answers = [
    {
      label: 'A',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'B',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: 'C',
      value: 1
    }
  ];
  
  let options = $(".your-options");
  let message1El = $(".message-1");
  let message2El = $(".message-2");
  answers.forEach(answer => {
    let a = $("<input></input>").attr({
      "name": 'question',
      "type":"radio",
      "value": answer.value
    });
    let l = $("<label></label>").text(answer.label);
    options.append(a, l);
  });
  
  $('input:radio[name="question"]').on('click', (event) => {
  let currentEl = event.currentTarget;
    if (currentEl.checked) {
      message1El.html('Option ' + currentEl.value + ' has just selected');
    }
  });
  
  // in case you get from other
  $('.check-selected-radio').on('click', () => {
    let checkedEl = $('.your-options').find('input:checked');
    
    if (checkedEl.length) {
      message2El.html('Ah ha! Option ' + checkedEl.val() + ' was selected');
    }
    
  });
```

```css
.your-options,
.message {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="your-options"></div>
<div class="message message-1"></div>
<div class="message message-2"></div>
<button class="check-selected-radio">Check selected radio</button>
```

Comment: I ended up creating a click event on each radio button and then reading value with event.currentTarget like in your sample. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="comfortfood"]:checked').value;
```

Dynamically read Radio value;

```
document.querySelector('input[name="'+questionnaire[currentQuestion].name+'"]:checked').value;
```

This is how you can get your value with javascript for the selected radio button.
which is answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value) thread earlier.

Comment: I have updated answer for dynamically read values for radio buttons.